# Unable to Filter from database in DJango

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

This is my view.py:

```py
def customer_dashboard(request,id):
    order = Order.objects.filter(customer=id)
    print(order)
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_dashboard.html', {'user':user, 'customer':customer})
```

I tried to print the results,and I got this

```
<QuerySet []>
```

But I am very sure that the data is available in database, url is also working fine as other datas could be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

if i may , just so it can be readable for people to give answers, please add your code in a readable format.

this is your code:

**Models:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

**Views:**

```
def customer_dashboard(request,id):
    order = Order.objects.filter(customer=id) 
    print(order) 
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_dashboard.html', {'user':user, 'customer':customer})
```

First: none of your context relate to your Queryset

according to your view the context should be "order",

```
return render(request, 'accounts/customer_dashboard.html', {'order':order})
```

Second: you queryset filters by id ,while you did mention the consumer as a whole,i assume your consumer i the user ordering right now, so probably you have registered users, you can do it like that:

```
order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id, customer=request.user)
```

as a result:

```
def customer_dashboard(request,order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id, customer=request.user)
    print(order) 
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_dashboard.html', {'order':order})
```

order_id would be in the url of that view, as <int:order_id >

hope that helps. good luck